# React Hook "useState" is called in function "increaseCounter" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is my Count component, I am new to react, using hooks I create a function inside a function, but    it gives this error

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

 const style = {
  color: "#1B9CFC",
};

function Counter(props) {
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

function increaseCounter() {
useState(setCount());
}

 return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="ms-5" style={style}>
       {count}
      </h1>
      <div className="m-2 p-4">
      <button className="btn btn-success m-2" onClick={increaseCounter}>
        +
      </button>
      <button className="btn btn-danger">-</button>
    </div>
 </div>
  );
 }

export default Counter;
```

This is the full error message

src\component\Counter.jsx
Line 11:5:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "increaseCounter" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: It's as the error says. Calling `useState` outside of a component body doesn't make any sense, so it's forbidden.

Comment: If you want to increase the counter, do `setCount(prev => prev + 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState(setCount());` is not the way to change state.To change state, call the `setCount()` and set a value inside it.

Here is your code :

```js
function increaseCounter() {
setCount(count => count + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write in this way:

> ```
> function increaseCounter() {
>     setCount(count+1)
> }
> ```

In the react, setState event is async. useState allows you to initialize react hook with state. So you cannot use useState to update the state.

Answer (score 0):

There are two points we need to check if we are getting this error.

- The function name "Counter" .It must start from the capital latter.
- function increaseCounter() {
  setCount(count+1)
  } useSatate will increase the count value as per clicking the button.